# getBoundingClientRect making a server request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am building a SPA with Next.js and was reviewing the requests made by the app to the server when I stumbled across multiple 404 errors.

After looking at the initiator of these requests, it led me to a line using getBoundingClientRect(). When I removed this line to see if it was an isolated issue, the requests were still there, but the initiator just moved to the next instance i've used getBoundingClientRect().

More information:

- The function below is called on window scroll.
- The function is working as intended.
- Its located inside a React component.
- The site is currently still in development.
- It looks like the request is made once per page load.
- I am using Chrome dev tools to review requests.
- The requests being made are replacing the last segment of the path of the page with false. E.g. http://localhost:8080/false or http://localhost:8080/portfolio/false

```
checkCurrentTheme() {
  const { menuTheme = 'dark', changeMenuTheme } = this.props;
  const bounds = this.ele.current.getBoundingClientRect();

  const min = bounds.top;
  const max = bounds.bottom;

  if (min <= 0 && max >= window.offsetHeight) {
    changeMenuTheme(menuTheme);
  }
}
```

Is this expected behaviour? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Definitely not expected no ;) In your position, I would not trust the dev tools tells the correct position. Continue removing stuff that can make a network request. Btw, what kind of request is it? XHR? Media, other?

Comment: Thank you for your help @Kaiido. The requests are for text/html. Looks like i've got myself a weird one!